# How can I tell how much it costs to run a low traffic WordPress site on GCP?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, billing

Started a GCP free trial, migrated two WordPress sites with almost zero traffic to test the service. Here's what I'm running for each of the two sites:

VM: g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory) 10gb SSD
Package: bitnami-wordpress-5-2-4-1-linux-debian-9-x86-64

After about 1-2 months it seems to show that $46 has been deducted from the $300 free trial credit. Is this accurate / typical? Am I looking at paying $20+ per month to process perhaps 100 hits to the site from myself, plus any normal bot crawling that happens? This is roughly 10 times more expensive than a shared hosting multi domain account available from other web hosts.

Overall, how can I tell how much it will actually cost, when it looks to me that GCP reports about $2 of resource consumption per month, a $2 credit, and somehow a $254 balance from $300? Also GCP says average monthly cost is 17 cents on one of the billing pages, which is different from the $2 and the $46 figures. I can't find any entry that would explain all the other resources that were paid/credited.

Does anyone else have experience how much it should cost to run the Bitnami WordPress package provided on GCP marketplace?

Comment: I did a similar test with a django website and it was about the same. I cannot speak as to exactly what the cost breakdown was as this was 3-4 years ago, but I was shocked that it was $20-30/month given it was mostly a test site and the only traffic was myself and my coworkers. I wonder if some of that is initial setup and resource costs and the price could eventually go down over time?

Comment: Also GCP says it costs 17 cents a month, which contradicts the other figures. Maybe licensing fees for free open source software, because I installed the Bitnami package, and resources for installing the packages?

Comment: Your question has no details on the services that you are using, instance sizes, storage or network bandwidth. Google has good billing information available in the Google Cloud Console. Spend some time learning what each item means. Then you can decide which services best fit your requirements. I organized a series of short videos on Google Cloud Billing: https://www.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/

Comment: I'm mostly wondering about how to judge the price of any service that I choose, since I spent a lot of time clicking around, watching videos and googling for answers, and am still confused. I will add more details to the question though, and thanks for the link to more videos to watch, maybe they will help.

Comment: Your setup probably uses Compute Engine virtual machines which are billed for every second they are on, regardless of the amount of traffic your website generates. To elevate the power of serverless you would need to move to a solution where you are billed for every request, like Cloud Run.

Comment: @Benjamin Wow thanks that is Exactly where I went wrong! I am on compute engine and thought it would behave like you are saying Cloud Run does, I will start reading about that next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Current Usage:**

Running 2x g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory) 10gb SSD Package 24x7 should have deducted around ~$26* USD from your free-trial.

[image]

I presume you need MySQL would cost you minimum of $7.67* per instance:
[image]

Assuming you used 2x MySQL instances it would have costed you ~$15

So $26 Compute + $15 DB + $5 (other network, dns cost etc) would come upto about $46. Please note that price would go up if you used compute for less than a month.

*
1. As you can see from the image, you could get sustained use discount if you run it for a full month

2. if you are planning to use it for even longer you can get bigger discount for commited use.

**Optimise for Cost**

Have a look at the cost calculator link to plan your usage. 
https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

Since compute and relational storage are the most cost prohibitive factor for you. If you are tech-savvy and open to experimentation you can try and use cloud run which should reduce your cost significantly but might add extra latency in serving your request. The link below shows how to set this up:

https://medium.com/acadevmy/how-to-install-a-wordpress-site-on-google-cloud-run-828bdc0d0e96

Currently there is no way around using database. Serverless databases could help bring down your cost but gcp does not over this at this point. AWS has this offering so gcp might come up with this in future.

**Scalability**

When your user base grows you might want to use

1. CDN which would help with your network cost.
2. Saving images to cloud storage would also help bring down your cost as disks  are more expensive and less scalable and has increased maintenance.

Hope this helps.